# unable to get customer custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

I am trying to save life time savings as customer attribute. After every successful purchase, I am incrementing the value.

To create the attribute I have below install script

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "life_time_total_saving",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Life Time Savings",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "life_time_total_saving");

$used_in_forms=array();

        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 0)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

config.xml:

```
<resources>
        <total_savings>
            <setup>
                <module>Ucs_Saving</module>
                <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </total_savings>
    </resources>
```

After running this script, I can able to see attribute created in `eav_attribute` but in customer object I cant find the same.

below is my script inside mycustomer dashboard.phtml

```
$customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($customerData);
```

But the object printed does not have the field `life_time_total_saving`.

Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make  sure ***`is_visible field`*** value **1**

```
 ->setData("is_visible", 1)
```

Comment: I have written a upgrade script with `is_visible field`  but its not working

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since no value stored for the user, it is no reflecting on customer object. +1 for your help

Comment: you are welcome